# In C#, how can an object that's inside a List itself know what index it is in the list

Tags: c#

Quite often I found myself in a situation of needing to know what index an item is in a List while enumerating through the list. Is there any way to do this with out having to resort to using a for(var i=0...) loop?

Ideally I would like to do something like this. 
e.g

```
foreach(SomeType item in myList){
  Console.Write(item.Index);
}
```

jQuery has this $(this).index();  which is something like what I would like in C#

Comment: `foreach(SomeType item in myList){  Console.Write(myList.IndexOf(item).ToString());}`

Comment: @Pikoh well, it will work correctly only in the case of distinct items in list. Otherwise it will return index of first element having the same value as current.

Comment: While that will work.  Ideally I don't want to need to refer directly to the parent list, as in some scenarios this might not be accessible.   I want to refer to the index as a property of the object. e.g item.Index

Comment: And why would you like to avoid using simple `for` loop?

Comment: Try to use Select((x, index) => [code]) or plain for loop

Comment: By adding such a property you are coupling your object to a List. What possible use case do you have for that? Maybe you shouldn't be using a List?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev well,that is true for a List<string> for example, but if the List type is a class, it will work

Comment: @MakkyNZ in what scenario would the parent list not be accesible?

Comment: @Pikoh, say for example, you pass the object into a method. Code inside that method might not have access to the parent list.  
e.g  foreach(var item in mylist){ doSomething(item); }
void doSomething(SomeType item) { Console.Write(item.index);}

Comment: You can always pass additional parameter to method like this.

Comment: @Dovydas  changing a methods parameter signature isn't always that easy.  Especially if it's implementing an interface,as a lot of other classes could be implementing the same interface. I'm looking for a solution that has none or very little impact on the rest of the code base.

Comment: @MakkyNZ there's no other way i think. Have in mind that to get the index of an item in a collection, this index must be in relation with the collection containing it. What if an item belongs to two collections? what index would you get if you did something like item.Index()?

Comment: @Pikoh  good point.  I guess that's why jQuery's $(this).index() is allowed, as an html element can't exist in two places